# log4j: logging a package, but excluding its sub-packages

Tags: java, configuration, log4j

Hi I'd like to exclude certain subpackages from being logged by one of my loggers, as they are being logged by another logger. Eg.

```
com.mysite.app = logger1
com.mysite.app.news = logger2
com.mysite.app.events = logger3
```

I'd like logger1 to only log anything with com.mysite.app (including com.mysite.app.utilities) not logged by logger2 and logger3. How could I do that?

*(help in properties format please, XML format for other's reference for bonus points)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always used to think that `log4j.logger.com.mysite.app = logger1` takes care of logging messages from subpackages too into `logger1`.

If you really don't want `logger2` and `logger3`'s messages from interfering with those of `logger1`, you need to set their additivity to `false`.

```
log4j.additivity.com.mysite.app.news=false
log4j.additivity.com.mysite.app.events=false
```

Comment: Hi Can you please help me on how to achieve the same with XML format?

Comment: Check the answer given by Saljack for this same question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46364936/8146873

Answer (score 2):

Have a try:

```
log4j.logger.com.mysite.app=info, stdout
log4j.additivity.com.mysite.app=false

log4j.logger.com.mysite.app.news=off, stdout
log4j.additivity.com.mysite.app.news=false

log4j.logger.com.mysite.app.events=off, stdout
log4j.additivity.com.mysite.app.events=false
```

Answer (score 1):

For XML configuration:

```
<logger name="com.mysite.app.news" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="logger2" />
</logger>    
<logger name="com.mysite.app.events" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="logger3" />
</logger>
```